# Weird graphical glitch when trying to change install path for Steam on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ati, games, 13.10, steam, bug-reporting

Ok so I am trying to change my installation directory for steam because Ubuntu is installed on my SSD and I have another terabyte HD. Everytime I try to change my installation path I get this weird graphical glitch.

[image]

Comment: This is probably a bug and should be reported to Steam. Also, what happens when you try to click 'Next'? Does it work?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the machine?

Comment: Yes I have the answer below fixed part of it but when I try to select a new directory it comes up with that messed up box. It wont let me change installation directories period.

Comment: mmm... I think that it's still a bug. You better report this to Steam Devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oibaf just added support for saucy so now is the time to use it:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf*; sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers; sudo apt-get update; sudo aptitude upgrade -y; sudo aptitude dist-upgrade -y; sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg-video-all -y
```

This should fix all of your issues now.

Comment: This fixed some of them. I still get that messed up box when I try to change installation directories.

Comment: If you haven't reported it already, report the bug with the image you displayed over at https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues?state=open